# How to build a keyworded tuple?

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to use ArgumentParser.set_defaults from argparse. I want a keyworded tuple like this: `parser.set_defaults(bar=42, baz='badger')`

I have the item from the output of ConfigParser.items which is: `('baz','badger')`.

How do I convert this into the keyworded tuple that set_defaults is expecting?

Comment: The items of terminology to know here are "mapping" and "keyword arguments".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list `[(key, value), (key, value), ...]`, you can turn it into a dict with `that_dict = dict(that_list)`. Then you can unpack it into `set_defaults`, i.e. `parser.set_default(**that_dict)`.